# Jquery не работает функция click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Первая функция работает, то есть вот эта когда кликаешь на `$('.new-favorites')`, а вот когда к нему добавляется класс `del-favorites`, то вообще ничего не происходит... В чем проблема?

```
$('.new-favorites').click(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        id = el.data('id');
        el.addClass('del-favorites');
        el.removeClass('new-favorites');
    });
    $('.del-favorites').click(function(){
        console.log('dsa');

    });
```

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.del-favorites', function(){ console.log('dsa') });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery >= 1.7

```
$('.new-favorites').on('click', function(){
    var el = $(this);
    id = el.data('id');
    el.addClass('del-favorites');
    el.removeClass('new-favorites');
});
$(document).on('click', '.del-favorites', function(){
    console.log('dsa');
});
```

Comment: у вас работает?

Comment: @David Web, должно все работать, .on() (или ранее как .live()) обрабатывает также динамические элементы

Comment: Вообще никак не работает

Comment: @David Web, немного изменил, https://jsfiddle.net/p3gsmyc5/5/